# Calling api for each Recycler View item on Android

Tags: java, android, api, android-recyclerview, adapter

My Fragment has a RecyclerView, and I must call an API for each RecyclerView item. But when I try the code below, the point of items are not loading correct or differently every time I refresh the page.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomerCardHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    CustomerCardsResultObject customerCardsResultObject = getList().get(position);
    if (customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName().equals("phpoint") && !customerCardsResultObject.isCardPointLoaded()) {
        //Api call
        holder.getPhPoint(customerCardsResultObject, position);
    } else {
        //Api call
        holder.getCardPoint(customerCardsResultObject, position);
    }

}
```

There are 2 methods here. I'm getting each point of each card by using their card id.

```
public void getPhPoint(CustomerCardsResultObject customerCardsResultObject, int position) {
    viewModelCustomer.getCustomerPhPoint((customerPhPointResponse, b, errorBody) -> {
        shimmer.stopShimmer();
        shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (b) {
            customerCardsResultObject.setCardPointLoaded(true);
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            String priceString = "";
            if (customerPhPointResponse.getResultObject() != null && customerPhPointResponse.getResultObject().getPhPoint() != null && customerPhPointResponse.getResultObject().getPhPoint() != 0.0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CODE 0 " + position + " " + customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName());
                priceString = df.format(customerPhPointResponse.getResultObject().getPhPoint());
                puan.setText(priceString);
                customerCardsResultObject.setCardPoint(customerPhPointResponse.getResultObject().getPhPoint());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "CODE 1 " + position + " " + customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName());
                customerCardsResultObject.setCardPoint(0.0);
                puan.setText("0,00");
            }
        } else {
            puan.setText("0,00");
            if (customerPhPointResponse != null && customerPhPointResponse.getResultMessage() != null)
                Log.d(TAG, "CODE 2 " + position + " " + customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName());
            else if (errorBody != null)
                Log.d(TAG, "CODE 3 " + position + " " + customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName());
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "CODE 4 " + position + " " + customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName());
        }
    });
}

public void getCardPoint(CustomerCardsResultObject customerCardsResultObject, int position) {
    viewModel.getPoint((getPointResponse, b, errorBody) -> {
        shimmer.stopShimmer();
        shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (b) {
            customerCardsResultObject.setCardPointLoaded(true);
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            String priceString = df.format(getPointResponse.getResultObject());
            puan.setText(priceString);
            customerCardsResultObject.setCardPoint(getPointResponse.getResultObject());
            Log.d(TAG, "CODE 5 " + position + " " + customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName());
        } else {
            customerCardsResultObject.setCardPoint(0.0);
            puan.setText("0,00");
            Log.d(TAG, "CODE 6 " + position + " " + customerCardsResultObject.getEnumTypeName());
        }
    }, customerCardsResultObject.getId());
}
```

How can I fix this ?
By the way, API is working correctly. I tried this on the postman.

Comment: In my opinion you should never do time consuming things like making network requests or file operations in `ViewHolder` everytime the user scrolls up and down the view will be recycled and the same function will be executed again and again. Please consider some alternative way

Comment: Be specific describing your problem, not just say "it is different each time". each time what?

Comment: @OdaiAl-Qohaly I mean every time I refresh the page. I edited btw.

Comment: This is probably has to do with the logic you use to populate viewholder. My advice is to simplify your logic , let's say comment out code of "else" condition leaving only code within "if" condition then test your app again ,if you find that problem solved then your problem is related to the code of "else" condition, otherwise try comment out the opposite. The "if else" I'm referring to is either the one inside of onBindViewHolder or inside each of the functions of holder itself.